# Flask: how to paginate cx_Oracle data between successive requests?

Tags: pandas, flask, pagination, stream, cx-oracle

My Flask app needs to return a huge dataframe to the client application.

I'm using the pandas function [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) to fetch chunks of data, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
sql = "select * from huge_table"
iterator = pd.read_sql(sql, con=my_cx_oracle_connection, chunksize=1000)
```

Where `iterator` would be used to fetch the whole data divided into small chunks of 1000 records each:

```
data = next(iterator, [])
while data:
   yield data
   data = next(iterator, [])
```

With this approach, I guess can "stream", or at least, paginate the data just as described in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/streaming/#basic-usage).

However, to be able to do so, I would need to retain the state of the iterator between the HTTP /GET requests. How should one do this? Do I need some sort of global variable? But then, what about multiple clients?!

I'm missing something to make it work properly, and avoid fetching the same part of the data over and over.

Thanks.

Comment: A solution is to repeat the query on each HTTP request with different params, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#limiting-rows.  Make sure to use bind variables.  Using Pandas may make this less convenient. If you need some kind of read-consistent query so that repeated HTTP request refer to the same snapshot of data, throw in an AS OF clause like https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-0BD1F4BD-894B-47BA-A44B-74BCA4CFD60E.

Comment: Also you should look at tuning fetching data from the query e.g  https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance.